# How do I link a table view controller cell to another view?

Tags: xcode

What I want is when you click on any cell in the table you go to a view. I also need for each different cell you click on the view you get taken to has different strings. However I don't know

1. how to link a table cell to another view when you press it
2. how do you change the detail view controller for each different cell
   you click on.

Thank-you for trying to help me.

Comment: Are you speaking about iOS? Creating a new iOS application in Xcode with the "Master-Detail Application" template should give you a good example to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a better understanding of how to use storyboards and then how to customize `UItableView` cells as per your needs.

You can know more about using storyboards in [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

And after you get familiar with storyboards, you should think about customizing `UItableView` cells , you can customize as per your needs.

See [this link](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html), will surely help you.

Please go through these well before you copy paste any code.

Answer (score -1):

1. create a segue from the tableview to the detail view controller
2. use `prepareForSegue:sender:` and something like

`[segue.destinationViewController setDetail:[self detailForIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]]];` inside that method

---

Just google segue UITableView or something like that for some examples / step-by-step tutorials / ..

---

*(There are other options too, like using the UITableView delegate mehthod `tableView: tableViewdidSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, but I think the segueing one is the easiest to understand)*