# How to pass Data from a UITableViewController to another UITableViewController? -iOS & Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Let's say the setup is

`Navigation Controller` -> `GradLevelUITableViewController` -> `DegreeUITableViewController` -> `View Controller`

where:

- Data structure is like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35802806/is-there-another-approach-to-a-huge-list-of-dictionaries-of-lists-for-ios-swift).
- `GradLevelUITableViewController` contains 3 cells namely `Undergrad`, `Grad`, `PostGrad`.
- `DegreeUITableViewController` displays `Colleges` as sections and `Degrees` as rows.
- `View Controller` contains a scrollable `TextView` for more info.

My question is, how do I pass data (particularly *a list that contains info about the selected `degree` to be passed again later on to the `TextView`* AND *what was selected*) from `GradLevelUITableViewController` to `DegreeUITableViewController` and tell `DegreeUITableViewController` that I clicked one of the three cells and show its corresponding `Colleges` and `Degrees`(e.g. if `Undergrad` was tapped, show only `Colleges` and `Degrees` for `Undergrad`).

I'm new to iOS and Swift Programming, I can't find a decent tutorial on passing data between View Controllers using Swift. Probably I don't know the exact term for this particular "connection".

I've tried these links:

- [How do I make multiple tableview cells to lead corresponding view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318781/how-do-i-make-multiple-tableview-cells-to-lead-corresponding-view-controllers)
- [How do I link a table view controller cell to another view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921787/how-do-i-link-a-table-view-controller-cell-to-another-view)
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1

and other tutorials that are mostly written in Objective-C. The 1st and 2nd link seems to be the answer but I'm not sure how to use it and how to pass what I need.

Comment: Please post your code, showing how you transition from GradLevelUITableViewController to DegreeUITableViewController.  There are two standard ways = presentViewController or using segues.

Comment: It would indeed be easier if you posted code. But generally how this is approached is, when a degree cell is tapped in GradLevelUITableViewController, you instantiate a new DegreeUITableViewController and pass in whatever info you want as constructor arguments, and then push that new controller onto the navigation stack.

Answer (score 1):

Something of this kind should do the trick

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if let grad = self.grads[indexPath.row] {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("pushDegree", sender: grad)
        }
    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "pushDegree" {
            guard
                let degreeVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DegreeViewController,

            else {
                return
            }
            degreeVC.grad = sender as! Grad
        }
```